# Display Query results in DataGridView

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, ado.net

I am working on my C# ADO.NET app. I have connected my SQL Server database with C# app, and I can perform simple CRUD operations. Now I want to execute queries and show results on my `DataGridView` when I click on button, for example finding person by name. I think I wrote my query good but every time I am clicking on button, i get error message. Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        IQueryable<Tab_Bday> name;
        using (var data = new BirthdayEntities()) 
        {
            name = from x in data.Tab_Bday
                    where x.Ime=="Peter"
                     select x;
        }
        dataGridView2.DataSource = name.ToList();               
    }
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL data in DataGridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163222/sql-data-in-datagridview)

Comment: The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

Answer (score 1):

Just by taking a simple look at it I noticed you're missing the `dataGridView2.DataBind();` method that is required for the proper population.

but, could you specify what error are you getting?

EDIT:

As I said in the comment, try setting the `DataSource` and `Databind` inside the using brackets after `select x;` that's because the `using` automatically closes the connection.

Comment: The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

Comment: Try setting the datasource inside the using brackets after select x; that's because the using automatically closes the connection.

Comment: No proble, I edited my answer so that it gets to be more clear to other users looking for answer.